# Delphi, find form by name

Tags: forms, delphi

how can I find form by name? On this form I have Edit (TEdit) and i would like to write something in this TEdit (its name e.g.: adress) but I have only form name.
Can you help me?

Comment: How did you manage to lose your form?

Comment: Do you mean how to find the form amongst the forms the application has created at run-time?

Comment: I mean, if you created the form, why don't you remember it in a variable. Why would you want to look something up by name?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a simpler way of finding a form by name. Since all of [auto-created](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Forms_%28dialog_box%29) form objects become owned by `Application` object and `TApplication` inherits from `TComponent`, you can either iterate thru [`Application.Components`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Classes.TComponent.Components) array property or use [`Application.FindComponent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Classes.TComponent.FindComponent) method.

```
var 
  Form: TForm;
begin
  Form := Application.FindComponent('LostForm1') as TForm;
  if Assigned(Form) then
    Form.Show
  else
    { error, can't find it }
```

Note that `FindComponent` is case-insensitive.

Comment: Note the use of auto-created forms. These are forms created using Application.CreateForm. If the form was created using MyForm := TMyForm.Create, then it will not be in the Application.Components collection.

Comment: @SiBrit, that depends on the `Owner` argument to `Create`. Normally, forms should be owned by `Application` unless there some special case like one-shot Create/ShowModal/Free, but in such case there would be no need to locate the form.

Answer (score 6):

This answer assumes you are making a VCL application. I don't know if FireMonkey has a similar solution.

All forms are added to the global Screen (declared in Vcl.Forms) object when they are created. Thus you can make a little helper function like this

```
function FindFormByName(const AName: string): TForm;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Screen.FormCount - 1 do
  begin
    Result := Screen.Forms[i];
    if (Result.Name = AName) then
      Exit;
  end;
  Result := nil;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx) function if you know the form title or the class name of the form.

Comment: I think the OP may be asking how to find the form from within inside the application that contains the form.